# Any Javascript library extract only the main body HTML and text?

Tags: javascript, nlp

I am looking for some Javascript-based library to fetch the HTML of the main body text for analysis purposes, by body text I mean something without navigation/sidebars and footers. Is there any library for that purpose?

A 3rd Party REST API will also work.

**Update:** I mean the main content of the article not stuff INSIDE the body tag. For instance main content of the article and related HTML

Comment: Do you really need a library?  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/body

Comment: Also: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent

Comment: @RobertHarvey err. I just updated the link, I meant Article/News content without any navigation and side bars

Comment: Are you looking for a general solution, or one that will work for a specific site?

Comment: A general solution, I need text analysis for article/news content. If it was specific I would have parsed it already

Answer (score -1):

Try this, it's pretty straightforward.
https://www.npmjs.com/package/puppeteer

Comment: How come it is relevant to my question?

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).